# Converting counts inside query result tables to percentages of total

Tags: postgresql

I have a table and want to calculate the percentage of total by store_id which each (category_id, store_id) subtotal represents. My code is below:

```
WITH
    example_table (name, store_id)
AS 
    (
        select name, store_id
        from category
        join film_category using (category_id)
        join film using (film_id)
        join inventory using (film_id)
        join rental using (inventory_id)
    )
SELECT name, store_id, cast(count(*) as numeric)/(SELECT count(*) FROM example_table)
FROM example_table
GROUP BY name, store_id
ORDER BY name, store_id
```

This code actually works, as in, it doesn't throw an error, only they're not the results I'm looking for. Here each of the subtotals is divided by the total across both stores and all 16 names. Instead, I want the subtotals divided by their respective store totals or divided by their respective name totals. 
I'm wondering how to perform calculations on those subtotals in general.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to explore the possibilities of using aggregate functions combined with an `OVER(PARTITION BY ...)` e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   name, store_id, store_id_count, name_count
FROM (
        select name, store_id
             , count(*) over(partition by store_id) as store_id_count
             , count(*) over(partition by name) as name_count
        from category
        join film_category using (category_id)
        join film using (film_id)
        join inventory using (film_id)
        join rental using (inventory_id)
    ) AS example_table
```

When using aggregate function with the over clause you get the wanted counts on each row of the result, and it seems that in this case you need this. Note that `select distinct` has been used simply to reduce the final number of rows returned, you might still need to use a `group by` but I am not sure if you do.

Once you have the needed values within the derived table (aliases as `example_table`) then it should be a simple matter of some arithmetic in the overall select clause.